# How to capture audio outputs (speakers, headphones etc), not inputs (microphone) in flutter android?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Is there a way to capture/listen to audio OUTPUTS (phone speakers, plugged-in headphones etc), not audio inputs (microphone) in Flutter? I'm making a flutter app that needs to listen/access the audio OUTPUT from the phone when either playing music or calling someone or anything else that outputs some sound from the phone.

I'm a beginner flutter developer and would really appreciate any help. Thank you...